# What is the expected number of coin tosses it would take to get N many heads OR N many tails?

Tags: probability

Where we do NOT require that the heads or tails be consecutive (though they may be!)

Obviously, this expectation, $E[T]$, is bound as follows: $N < E[T] < 2N - 1$

And obviously $E[T] = \sum_{i=N}^{n=2N-1}i*P[Game \ Ends \ On \ i^{th} \ Round]$, where $\sum_{i=N}^{n=2N-1}P[Game \ Ends \ On \ i^{th} \ Round] = 1$

But how would one find such a probability for an arbitrary $i \in \{N, N+1, ..., 2N-1\}$?

Comment: You might be asking a question related to negative binomial distribution. check this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Well this is  Banach matchbox problem... :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem

Comment: And, according to the same reference, your expectation will satisfy $2n - \mathbb E[T_n] \sim (2/ \sqrt{\pi}) \sqrt{n}$ - I have not done the calculation again...

Comment: I don't think this problem is quite the same as the Banach Matchbox Problem, but it is certainly similar! I'll go and play around with it for a bit.

Comment: @Olivier: according to my answer, $2n-\mathbb{E}[T_n]=2n\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\sim\frac{2n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, which agrees.

Comment: @TeenPhilosopher : let's bet ? ;-) More seriously, which difference do you see ?

Comment: @Olivier: In the matchbox problem, the game goes until a matchbox is found empty upon attempting to get a match rather than when taking the last match. This game ends when the last match is taken from a box. Given that game, it could go on for $2N+1$ turns.

Comment: Yep, time to reach the N-th 0 or 1 (whichever comes first) here rather than the N+1-th in the matchbox (time the match is found empty). The parameter has to be adjusted. "Au temps pour moi" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the game ends at round $i$ is:$$\binom{i-1}{N-1}2^{1-i}$$If e.g. the game ends with a tail at $i$-th round then among the $i-1$ results in the former rounds must be $N-1$ tails. There are $\binom{i-1}{N-1}$ configurations for that and each of them has probability $2^{1-i}$ to occur. Further we must multiply with the probability that a tail will appear at $i$-th trial which is $\frac12$. Same outcome if the game ends with a head at $i$-th round so a multiplication with $2$ is also needed.

So to be found is:

$$\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1}i\binom{i-1}{N-1}2^{1-i}=2N\sum_{i=N}^{2N-1}\binom{i}{N}2^{-i}$$

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you so much! I would like to think that I gave this problem an honest and fair try, but it seems that my combinatorics abilities still has quite a ways to go!

Comment: You are welcome. Just keep on developing these abilities. Your mathematical maturity will grow then.

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary Formula**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\sum_{m=n}^{2n}\frac1{2^m}\binom{m}{n}\\
&=\sum_{m=n}^{2n}\frac1{2^m}\left[\binom{m-1}{n}+\binom{m-1}{n-1}\right]\\
&=\frac12\sum_{m=n-1}^{2n-1}\frac1{2^m}\left[\binom{m}{n}+\binom{m}{n-1}\right]\\
&=\frac12\left[a_n-\frac1{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+a_{n-1}+\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\right]\\[3pt]
&=\frac12(a_n+a_{n-1})\\[9pt]
&=a_{n-1}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
and since $a_0=1$, we have
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{m=n}^{2n}\frac1{2^m}\binom{m}{n}=1}\tag2
$$

---

**The Answers**

The number of ways to get to $n$ heads on flip $m$ and not on flip $m-1$ is 
$$
\binom{m}{n}-\binom{m-1}{n}=\binom{m-1}{n-1}\tag3
$$
This is also the number of ways to get to $n$ tails on flip $m$ and not on flip $m-1$. Thus, the probability of getting to $n$ heads or $n$ tails on flip $m$ and not on flip $m-1$ is
$$
\frac2{2^m}\binom{m-1}{n-1}=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac1{2^{m-1}}\binom{m-1}{n-1}}\tag4
$$
Note that $(2)$ shows that
$$
\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\frac1{2^{m-1}}\binom{m-1}{n-1}=1\tag5
$$
That is, the probability of getting $n$ heads or $n$ tails by flip $2n-1$ is $1$. The expected duration is then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}\binom{m-1}{n-1}
&=2n\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1}\frac1{2^m}\binom{m}{n}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2n\left(1-\frac1{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\right)}\tag6
\end{align}
$$

Comment: To match the variables in the question, $m\mapsto i$ and $n\mapsto N$.

Comment: What was your intuition to quickly observe that $\sum_{m=n}^{2n} \frac{1}{2^m}\binom{m}{n} = 1$?

Comment: $(4)$ is derived through probabilistic arguments, and $(5)$ needs to hold for $(4)$ to be a probability distribution.